# Able to log array in console, but can't loop through it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Running into a problem. In react I'm grabbing data from a json api. Everything worked fine until I tried to display it. Except, I'm able to log it on the console.

What the console logs:

[image: pic]

```
<ul role="list" className="divide-y divide-gray-200 dark:divide-gray-700">
{username !== "null" && leaderlist.length > 2 && console.log(leaderlist) && leaderlist.map((leader, index) =>
       <li className="py-3 sm:py-4 text-white">
           Log 
        </li>
      )}
     <li className="py-3 sm:py-4 text-white">
         list length {leaderlist.length} 
     </li>
   </ul>
```

What it displays:

[image]

The code that sets

```
const [leaderlist, setleaderlist] = React.useState([]);
fetch(`${baseurl}/allusers`)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data => {setleaderlist(data); console.log(data)})
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: you can access the properties inside the map statement as leader.average, leader.user etc

Comment: @cmgchess The issue is that it's not listing anything. Even though it clearly has children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
username !== "null" && leaderlist.length > 2 && console.log(leaderlist) && leaderlist.map((leader, index)
```

`console.log(leaderlist)` does not have a return value and thus `leaderlist.map((leader, index) ...)` does not run since you're using `&&`.
You need to remove the `console.log` statement or use `;` instead of `&&`.